# pd.get_dummies only keep dummy value name as dummy column name

Tags: python, concatenation

I'm trying to do a pd.get_dummies and concat it back to the datarame. It went well but I would like to only return the dummy value names as dummy column name. I have a really big daraframe. Instead of renaming the columns, is there any way to solve this issue? Any support is appreciated!

Dataframe

```
Number   Fruit
  One    Apple
  Two    Orange
  Three  Banana
  Four   Lemon
```

Code

```
dum = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruit'])
df = pd.concat([df, dum], axis=1)
df
```

Current output

```
Number   Fruit   Fruit_Apple   Fruit_Orange   Fruit_Banana   Fruit_Lemon
  One    Apple        1             0              0              0
  Two    Orange       0             1              0              0
  Three  Banana       0             0              1              0
  Four   Lemon        0             0              0              1
```

Desired output

```
Number   Fruit      Apple         Orange         Banana         Lemon
  One    Apple        1             0              0              0
  Two    Orange       0             1              0              0
  Three  Banana       0             0              1              0
  Four   Lemon        0             0              0              1
```

Comment: I think you need to set the columns `names` in `pd.concat` like so: `df = pd.concat([df, dum], axis=1, names = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Lemon")`. Could you give it a try?

Answer (score 4):

Let's use some parameters in pd.get_dummies to eliminate prefix and prefix separator:

```
dum = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruit'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
pd.concat([df, dum], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Number   Fruit Number  Apple  Banana  Lemon  Orange
0    One   Apple    One      1       0      0       0
1    Two  Orange    Two      0       0      0       1
2  Three  Banana  Three      0       1      0       0
3   Four   Lemon   Four      0       0      1       0
```