# python pandas - convert values to column names and fill with zeros and ones

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert categorical values to column names and fill with zeros and ones.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'province' : ['Ontario', 'Manitoba', 'Quebec'], 'species' : ['a', 'b', 'c']})

   province species
0   Ontario       a
1  Manitoba       b
2    Quebec       c
```

I want to reshape the data frame above so that the values in `species` turn into column names, and the values of the new columns indicate presence or absence. The new data frame should look like this:

```
   province  a  b  c
0   Ontario  1  0  0
1  Manitoba  0  1  0
2    Quebec  0  0  1
```

Comment: `x = pd.get_dummies(x, columns=['species'])` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36285489) or `x = pd.get_dummies(x, columns=['species'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')` for exact output.

Comment: @Henry, I didn't find an option not to add the prefix though

Comment: @mozway The second option with `, prefix='', prefix_sep='')` works fine no? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62902495/15497888)

Comment: You're right, I had tried False for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
(pd.crosstab(x['province'], x['species'])
   .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
   province  a  b  c
0  Manitoba  0  1  0
1   Ontario  1  0  0
2    Quebec  0  0  1
```

*NB. crosstab will give you the **number** of found values, so if you have duplicates you can have `2`/`3`/etc.*

or [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
pd.get_dummies(x, columns=['species'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

output:

```
   province  a  b  c
0   Ontario  1  0  0
1  Manitoba  0  1  0
2    Quebec  0  0  1
```